# How to redirect from managed bean method to specific facelet?

Tags: jsf, redirect

Here is a method from java bean.

```
public String AmILoggedIn(){
        if(false){
            return "true";
        }else{
            return "false";
        }
    }
```

By using following facelet I am submitting data to `AmILoggedIn`:

```
<h:form>
    Name:<h:inputText value="#{student.name}"></h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{newJSFManagedBean.AmILoggedIn}"/>
</h:form>
```

I submit data to function `AmILoggedIn`. As `AmILoggedIn` returns a string, how can I redirect this string to some specific facelet?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .redirect("urlToRedirectTo");
```